# Randomly test n combinations of factors in dataframe

Tags: r

I am trying to compare the p-values of multiple random trials of 'n' number of groupings from a single dataframe.

For example, I have the dataframe:

```
data_df = data.frame("Test" = c(rep(1,6), rep(2,6), rep(3,6), rep(4,6)), "Individual" = rep(seq(1,6,1),4), "Value1_x" = runif(24), "Value1_y" = runif(24), "Value2_x" = runif(24), "Value2_y" = runif(24))
```

There are 4 trials, 6 individuals in two test conditions (x,y) and two measured values (value1, value2).

I would like to generate a resulting dataframe that:

1. Contains the p-values for a t-test for each value between individuals in group X and group Y, for each test
2. Contains the p-values for the two measured values between the groups x and y for any random combination of 2 "Test"s with 10 combinations of tests (with replacement) [e.g. compute the p-value between groups X and Y for measured value 1 and measured value 2 for tests 1 and 4]
3. Contains the p-values for Value1 and Value2 between the groups x and y for any random combination of 3 "Test"s with 10 combinations of tests (with replacement)

and so on and so forth up to a combination of 4 "Test"s, which is the total number of tests I have.

I could write a for-loop that would randomly combine 'n' Tests for 'z' combinations, but I was wondering if there was a faster/more efficient way to do this?

Comment: The speed of for-loops is determined by the body of the loop. So it's likely to be as efficient as an lapply implementation. Your description of the task is unclear. You should show one instance of calculating a "p-value for a t-test for each value between individuals in group X and group Y, for [one]  test".

Comment: could you show exactly what you are looking for? eg can you give an example of the first t.test you are looking for?

Comment: check `pairwise.t.test`